# External hdd is not working properly after setting it into enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I had a seagate external hdd. Its external port where cable inserts got broken. The only choice i had was to change its case to 2.5 hdd enclosure. After doing that whenever i connect it to the system it stop read write after few minutes. And always prompt for format disk. Before changing the case it was working fine. So is this the hardware issue ?  Is there some fault in the enclosure ?  Can I fix this using some HDD repair software ?

Comment: Does the disk work consistently connected directly to a PC (without enclosure)?

Comment: I have not checked it directly. Because i generally use it with laptop.

Comment: What is the make and model of the new enclosure you're using?

Comment: It is Terabyte Gold